# Beginner question in probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

i'm a beginner in statistics and probability and i need help with a given problem please.

We are given a guy who has a machine and a button, the outcames when he presses the button are:

a)Music plays
b)Nothing happens

It is 7 times more likely that nothing happens than for the music to play.

A. The guy presses the button. Give the probability that music will play.

B. The guy presses the button 50 times.

1. Construct a space of probability which will describe this experience.
2. Define a random varuable which will count the number of times that music will play. Find its law and expectancy.

C. The guy has 2 options:
a)Press the button 10 times.
b)Press the button until the music plays.

1. Construct the probability space which describes the second option, option b)
2. Define a random variable which will count the number of times which the guy needs to press the button in order for the music to play and find its expectancy. (again, for option b))
3. In case he chooses option b), find the probability that he will need to press the button 10 or more times in order for the music to play.
   Which option would you reccomend to the guy if he wants to choose the fastest ending one?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a Bernoulli trial (more specifically a binomial distribution)(an action is performed and only one of the two possible outcomes is happens at once). Bernoulli's trials are a foundation and will be heavily used later in your class and I highly recommend you attempt this question by yourself.

Here are a few tips to get you started:

(1) Define one of the two outcomes as success and the other as failure

(2) Assign probabilities to each of these (failure and success) (P(failure)+P(success)=1)

(3) Assign a meaningful random variable.
In your case, I would assign the random variable

$$X=1\, \text{ if music plays} $$
$$X=0\, \text{ if it doesn't}$$

(4) Let p be the probability of success$\implies$ (1-p) is the probability of failure

(5) This problem can be solved intuitively or using a general formula. Below is the general formula
$$P(X=k)=(p^k)(1-p)^{n-k}{n\choose{k}}$$

(6) Further required formulas are E(X)=p and V(X)=p(1-p)

The second part of the question uses a geometric distribution (Trials till success). Just like the distribution before, a general formula and setup can be easily located in the text that you are using.